# Changing query from LINQ QUERY syntax to METHOD SYNTAX

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple code that projects the permutation of a given string argument.
I need to change the query from this Code from LINQ QUERY syntax to MEthod Syntax.
Will appreciate any help.

```
public static List<string> SinglePermutations(string s)
{
     var result = new List<string> { "" };
           
     foreach (var c in s)
     {
           result = (from r in result
                     from a in s
                     select $"{r}{a}").ToList();
     }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need to do so?

Comment: just for learning and for better understanding of nested methods.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper to the rescue:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SinglePermutations(string s)
{
    return s.Aggregate(result, (current, c) => current.SelectMany(r => s, (r, a) => $"{r}{a}")
        .ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! . I use VS without ReShaper.  So i guess I need to spend a few minutes to figure out your code.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper, without converting for loop. So one step before @kalu93 answer.

```
    public static List<string> SinglePermutations(string s)
{
    var result = new List<string> { "" };
   
    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        result = (result.SelectMany(r => s, (r, a) => $"{r}{a}")).ToList();
    }

    return result;
}
```